# Adding a condition to retrieve certain data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a conditional expression to the code so that the data that has the field 'category' entered as BS in firebase realtime database will be called and displayed. Here is a picture of the database table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxDZD.jpg

How do I add an expression to the following code so that only "English for Career Development" will be displayed and not "Excel Skills for Business" since "English for Career Development", or test 4 has a field category = 'bs' but test 5 doesn't so it will not show up.

Code:

```
class _BusinessPage1State extends State<BusinessPage1> {
  List<AllCourses> coursesList = [];

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    DatabaseReference referenceAllCourses = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('AllCourses');
    referenceAllCourses.once().then(((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      coursesList.clear();
      var keys = dataSnapshot.value.keys;
      var values = dataSnapshot.value;
      for(var key in keys){
        AllCourses allCourses = new AllCourses(
          values [key]["courseName"],
          values [key]["teacher"],
          values [key]["category"],
        );
        coursesList.add(allCourses);
      }
      setState(() {
        //
      });
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: ()
            {Navigator.pop(context);
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>homepage()));}),
          title: Text("Creator's Club"),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff2657ce),
          elevation: 0,),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Business', style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff2657ce),
                    fontSize: 27,
                  ),),
                  Text('Choose which course you want to study.', style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                      fontSize: 20
                  ),),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            coursesList.length == 0 ? Center(child: Text("Loading...", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),)): ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemCount: coursesList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                  return CardUI(coursesList[index].courseName, coursesList[index].teacher, coursesList[index].category);
                                }
                            )
                          ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
            )
        )
    );
  }
}

Widget CardUI (String courseName, String teacher, String category){
  return Card(
    elevation: 1,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    color: Color(0xffd3defa),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xffd3defa),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(17)),
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.star_border_rounded ,
                      color: Color(0xff2657ce),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 15,),
                Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: (){},
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(courseName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                                SizedBox(height: 5),
                                Text(teacher, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey)),
                                SizedBox(height: 5),
                                Text(category, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                    ]
                )
              ]
          )
        ],
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

Code for 'AllCourses' :

```
class AllCourses {
  String courseName;
  String teacher;
  String category;

  AllCourses(this.courseName, this.teacher, this.category);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition to check if the category is 'bs' before adding the course to the coursesList:

```
for(var key in keys){
    AllCourses allCourses = new AllCourses(
      values [key]["courseName"],
      values [key]["teacher"],
      values [key]["category"],
    );
    if(allCourses.get('category') == 'bs')
        coursesList.add(allCourses);
}
```

Comment: It tells me that "The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'AllCourses'."

Comment: try allCourses['category'] instead of allCourses.get('category')

Comment: Now I get the error of "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'AllCourses'". Haha, I think I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: please edit your question and add AllCourses class code in it, so that I can (hopefully) give you the exact answer

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question and added it! There's nothing much in that code. Thanks a lot for helping out.

Comment: ok, try allCourses.category.toString() instead of allCourses.get('category')

Comment: I keep getting a "W/System  (20901): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null." Does this have something to do with the Android Emulator having no internet?